# Is there any way to modify SQL view in OracleDB without dropping or recreating it?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a view:

```
CREATE VIEW employees
SELECT e.employeeFirstName , e.employeeLastName
FROM employee e;
```

I want to add **WHERE** block to sort out employees who don't have manager. But I want to alter(modify) existing view rather then recreate it. How can I accomplish that?

It's what I've tried so far, but got an error:

```
ALTER VIEW employees
SELECT e.employeeFirstName , e.employeeLastName
FROM employee e
WHERE manager IS NOT NULL;
```

I know that there is **CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW .. AS** command, but I'm wondering if there is something else like **ALTER**.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `create or replace view` would be the standard way of doing this.  Is there some reason that this doesn't work for you?  Or some problem that it causes?

Comment: @JustinCave I've been asked to modify it, but not to drop or recreate, it seems like create or replace view command recreate view, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Have you asked exactly what problem they're trying to avoid?  Not dropping it seems reasonable since that would remove things like grants.  `create or replace` wouldn't affect grants, though.

Comment: @JustinCave it’s home work task , so I want to be sure that I’m doing right

Comment: Justin nailed it: CREATE OR REPLACE is the syntax for ALTER in Oracle for this case.

Comment: @HermannBaer is ALTER SQL server command ?

Comment: @GipsyKing - I am not a SQL Server expert, but quickly looking at their online doc an ALTER VIEW in SQL Server is the equivalent to a CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW in Oracle .. to the extent those two can be equivalent. My read of it.

Comment: The [ALTER VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-VIEW.html#GUID-0DEDE960-B481-4B55-8027-EA9E4C863625) in Oracle is something different. It does not change the SHAPE of the view definition, but alters some characteristics of a view (e.g. constraints). Hope that helps.

Comment: If it is a homework task, `create or replace view` would almost certainly be the expected approach.  Anything else would be highly estoeric.

Comment: "*but not to drop or recreate*" probably means to not use `drop view ...; create view ...;` and is something different than `create or replace view ...`. drop/create will make you lose all defined privileges on the view, while `create or replace` will retain those.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the views in Oracle using "**create or replace view**". There is no other way to edit the view without dropping and recreating it.